# parallel operation execution time varies on allocating dynamic memory vs static memory

Tags: c, memory-management, parallel-processing, openmp

I have wrote a code to multiply two n by n matrices using openmp parallel for(for the outer loop).I have given the array size at compile time. I wish to give n as 2000. However as a second version I wrote the same code by dynamically allocating spaces for three matrices and giving the size of n (2000) as an argument. The two execution times I got for both versions when n = 2000 is differs in large. For 1st version (static allocation) it is around 13 seconds and for 2nd version (dynamic allocation) it is around 32 seconds. But both gives around same time for n<=1000. I only measure time for the parallel multiplying operation.So how could these two approaches give me different results? (the only change is the memory allocation type)

Here is version 1

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <omp.h>

#define N 1000
double A[N][N], B[N][N], C[N][N]; // declaring matrices of NxN size
int main ()
{
  /* DECLARING VARIABLES */
  int i, j, m; // indices for matrix multiplication
  double t_1; // Execution time measures
  /* FILLING MATRICES WITH RANDOM NUMBERS */
  srand ( time(NULL) );
  for(i=0;i<N;i++) {
    for(j=0;j<N;j++) {
        A[i][j]= (rand()%10);
        B[i][j]= (rand()%10);
    }
  }
  double st=omp_get_wtime();
  for(i=0;i<N;i++)
  {
    for(j=0;j<N;j++)
    {
        for(m=0;m<N;m++)
        {
            C[i][j]+=A[i][m]*B[m][j];
        }
    }
  }
  /* TIME MEASURE + OUTPUT */
  double en=omp_get_wtime();
  printf("Serial: %lf\n",en-st);
}
```

And here is the second version

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <omp.h>

int N = 0; // no of columns and rows of a matrix
double **A, **B, **C; // declaring pointers for matrices of NxN size

void getArguments(int argc, char *argv[]);

int main (int argc, char *argv[])
{
/* DECLARING VARIABLES */
int i, j, m; // indices for matrix multiplication
double t_1; // Execution time MEASURES
getArguments(argc,argv);

/* ALLOCATE MEMORY FOR MATRIX A */
A = (double **) malloc( sizeof(double *) * N);
for(i = 0;i < N; i++)
{
    A[i] = (double *) malloc(sizeof(double *) * N);
}

/* ALLOCATE MEMORY FOR MATRIX B */
B = (double **) malloc( sizeof(double *) * N);
for(i = 0;i < N; i++)
{
    B[i] = (double *) malloc(sizeof(double *) * N);
}

/* ALLOCATE MEMORY FOR MATRIX C */
C = (double **) malloc( sizeof(double *) * N);
for(i = 0;i < N; i++)
{
    C[i] = (double *) malloc(sizeof(double *) * N);
}

/* FILLING MATRICES WITH RANDOM NUMBERS */
srand ( time(NULL) );
for(i = 0;i < N;i++) {
    for(j = 0;j < N;j++) {
        A[i][j] = (rand() % 10);
        B[i][j] = (rand() % 10);
    }
}

double st = omp_get_wtime();
#pragma omp parallel for private(m,j)
for(i = 0;i < N;i++) {
    for(j = 0;j < N;j++) {
        C[i][j] = 0.; // set initial value of resulting matrix C = 0
        for(m = 0;m < N;m++) {
            C[i][j] = A[i][m] * B[m][j] + C[i][j];
        }
    }
}

/* TIME MEASURE */
double en = omp_get_wtime();
printf("Parallel: %lf\n",en - st);

/* FREE MEMORY */
for(i = 0;i < N; i++){
    free(A[i]);
}
free(A);
for(i = 0;i < N; i++){
    free(B[i]);
}
free(B);
for(i = 0;i < N; i++){
    free(C[i]);
}
free(C);
}

void getArguments(int argc, char *argv[]){
// Check the N
if (argc != 2) {
    printf("Please give a valid number for N\n");
    exit(0);
}
N = (int) strtol(argv[1], (char **) NULL, 10);
if (N == 0) {
    printf("Please give a number for N more than 0\n");
    exit(0);    
}

}
```

Comment: The first version allocates an array of arrays (i.e. a 2-D array in common parlance), whereas the second version allocates an array of pointers, each of which points to another array. There is more indirect memory access (through pointer deference) in the second version.

Comment: "declaring pointers for matrices of NxN size" - There is no pointer to a matrix (aka 2D array). A pointer is not an array!

Comment: @IanAbbott so is this why the second version take more time beacuse of the indirect memory access?

Comment: It's partly due to indirect memory access, although if the compiler does a reasonable job of optimization and can hold the current element of the array of pointers in a register during a full iteration of the outer loop, then it should only slow down the outer loop a bit. The remaining slow down may be due to more cache misses in the second version due to non-contiguous data, and also because the compiler does not know the dimensions at compile-time so needs to do more calculations at run-time.

Comment: got it thank you @IanAbbott

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are three major differences with the dynamic allocation:

1. The data is not allocated contiguously, as each row is allocated separately. This causes less efficient memory access, e.g. due to caching, prefetchers.
2. Each element access is indirect, through the pointer for the row. This is less efficient than computing the memory location just by the two indices.
3. `N` is no longer known at compile time, so the compiler has to generate more general purpose code for the loops over `N`.